# How to install tomcat use it in intellij. Ubuntu

Tags: java, docker, ubuntu, tomcat, intellij-idea

**What I try to do**

I try to install tomcat on Ubuntu 18.4. Then I want to create simple `JavaEnterprise` app in `InteliJ Ultimate` with `RESTfulWebService` and `WebApplication`.

**Ubuntu installation**

I ran `sudo apt-get install tomcat9` and installation went sussessfully.

**InteliJ configuration**

However I don't know what to write in InteliJ configuration in `Tomcat Home` empty box. All the time I am getting error `'The selected directory is not valid Tomcat home'` .

[image]

**Possible solution, but I don't want to install tomcat manually**

It may be caused with a fact that it is recommended to install tomcat manually? https://www.javahelps.com/2015/03/install-apache-tomcat-on-ubuntu.html

I dont want to install it like that because uninstalling it later will be to hard for me and I will have mess in my system.

**Docker installation**

I gave up `apt-get` solution and I installed tomcat in docker with command:
    sudo docker run  tomcat:9.0

I opened Docker tab in InteliJ:

[image: Ubuntu 18.4, InteliJ IDEA Ultimate, docker,]

I don't know how to inform InteliJ that in Docker Container called `recursing_haibt`
is a tomcat server which will handle simple HelloWorld app and open it in browser

[image]

I don't know what to do.

Comment: Try to set Tomcat home to `/usr/share/tomcat9` and Tomcat Base to `/var/lib/tomcat9`

Answer (score 0):

when i got this kind of stuck i got this documentation and rectified it
https://askubuntu.com/questions/968089/how-to-add-tomcat-8-into-intellij-idea